# S3 copy inside lambda function timing out

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I've got a Lambda function written in Python using Boto3 and setup to fire off when a file is put into an S3 bucket.  I want to copy that file to another S3 bucket across account.  Here is the code:

```
source =  boto3.resource('s3')
destination = boto3.resource('s3',
    aws_access_key_id='<redacted>',
    aws_secret_access_key='<redacted>')
source_bucket = source.Bucket(bucket)
destination_bucket = destination.Bucket('targetBucket')
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': bucket,
    'Key': key
}
destination_bucket.copy(copy_source, key)
```

When the Lambda function fires, everything seems to go well, but the copy never happens.  When that line fires off, I get the following message in my logs.  It looks like the connection to the S3 bucket is timing out.  I've verified that it doesn't appear to be a permissions issue.

> [INFO]    2017-01-25T19:33:59.400Z    c942ee38-e334-11e6-850d-45d8f93ed656    Starting
>   new HTTPS connection (1): [source-bucket].s3.amazonaws.com

Would anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you place the function in a VPC?

Comment: How big is the file? It's possible that it's just too big to copy in the time frame.

Comment: The files are pretty small.  I'm using jpeg files around 1 Mb for testing.  Actual usage will be small xml files.

Comment: The function is in a VPC, but in trying to debug, I temporarily opened the bucket to the world.  I was able to hit the file in S3 from a browser outside of AWS.  But it's not something directly occurred to me.  I'll try poking around that.

Comment: In a VPC, the Lambda function must be associated with a private subnet, equipped with a NAT device, or you need an S3 VPC Endpoint.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot nailed it.  I needed to set an S3 VPC Endpoint.  Once I did that, the error message changed.  I'm not getting an HTTP 403.  *sigh*  I'm off to the world of IAM and Bucket policies.  Thanks, Michael!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Michael-sqlbot above, I needed an S3 VPC Endpoint.